# Migrating data between different schemas

Tags: database, django, postgresql

I have a small django website where people have signed up and uploaded pictures and stuff.

I now want to rebuild the website API. This will change the database schema and I want to migrate all the user information from old database to new database.

Whats the best practice of doing this? Links to tutorials will be helpful.

The database backend is postgres-postgis.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to data migration. In my previous employer we rewrote much of the code from scratch and before deploying the new application we had to migrate old data. Two methods are:

1. Migrate data from the first schema directly from the DB: This is
   very useful especially if the data you have in legacy DB is huge. If
   you let the DB copy from one table/database to another it will be extremely
   fast. You need to have SQL knowledge for this though (google 'insert into from another database').
2. Write a script or django command to load the data into django models and go from there. This will not be as fast as DB option but it may be easier to code and depending on your scale of changes, your only option. If you are going to do some computation beforehand then a high level language such as python will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might go with the second option. Ill see if someone else answers before accepting your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Just wanted to add though, data migration is a hard topic and development takes time. Actually migrating data also may take time if you have huge data. Aim should be minimizing downtime and moving data consistently (not copying data more then once for example).